# Comparing results if there have been no similar studies

Tags: phd, publications, research-process, thesis

I examined seven years of financial data for a given country. However, there have been no similar studies that have the same sample as mine and cover a seven-year period (most study just one year in my area in this country). Also, I used a new measurement of one of the variables, which makes the results difficult to compare.

> How can I compare the results of my study with existing results in such circumstances?

Comment: Did you ask your supervisor first?

Comment: I assume Dmitry is asking because your supervisor is presumably familiar with the area you're working in, and how this sort of problem is typically dealt with in your field. So your supervisor is the best one to ask.

Comment: @user48932: Because your advisor should generally be your first point of contact to answer questions such as this.

Comment: This site is for Q&A from which other users can potentially benefit. As you said, your research situation is quite unique, and your supervisor is really the best person to consult with.

Comment: "I need to widen my gaze and listen different perspectives".  Sounds great.  Before you can listen to a different perspective though you need to listen to one perspective.  If you have an important methodological question about your thesis and your first instinct is to ask it in very general terms to a bunch of strangers on the internet....Well, we *are* trying to give you perspective.  Our perspective is that you should reflect on why you don't want to discuss this with your advisor.  Most other students in your situation certainly would.

Comment: @user48932 On StackExchange sites, people ask questions in comments so that they can get additional details about your situation in order to give you a better, more focused answer. That is how the site works. You are free to ignore any questions you don't want to answer (although this might not be productive), but you should [be polite](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) about it.

Answer (score 7):

Only your advisor can give you advice on how to analyze your *particular* data set. In general, however, when looking at a new data set I start by asking the following questions:

- What is known about X from past studies? Is the new data consistent with this? If not, can you find out why?
- What is *not* known about X from past studies, that this new data can give insight into? (You must have some idea about what this data will offer, or you wouldn't have bothered with it, right?)

where X is whatever you're interested in studying.

Comment: what new data? people studied the same data but not for seven years ! please read the question before you answer. thank you

Comment: @user48932 The "new data" here is the set of seven years of data (vs. the smaller subsets of data that everyone else has studied, i.e. "past studies").